# Set text and get text from clipboard

Tags: android, clipboard

In Android, I need some code to "get text" and "set text" in the clipboard.

For example I want to put "asd" in memory and after that paste it from clipboard.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? As an Android user, I've never seen an app that does this.

Comment: @Wesley for example keepass does this, to automatically clear the clipboard after some time.

Comment: `ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
        if (clipboard != null && clipboard.getPrimaryClipDescription().hasMimeType(MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN)) {
            ClipData.Item item = clipboard.getPrimaryClip().getItemAt(0);
            String yourText =item.getText().toString();
        }`

Answer (score 91, accepted):

```
ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE); 
clipboard.setText("Text to copy");
clipboard.getText();
```

Comment: which package is ClipboardManager? android.cotent or android.text, hm and it seems to be deprecated

Comment: @wutzebaer The ClipboardManager as used here is in [`android.text`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/ClipboardManager.html). The newer interface is at [`android.content`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ClipboardManager.html)

Comment: Now **deprecated**!

Comment: **Since API 11** clipboard.setPrimaryClip(ClipData.newPlainText(text, text));

Comment: Do this w/ the new API: 
ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("message", msgText.getText());
clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);

Comment: getText returns only the last copied data. How can I access all data from clipboard ?