# How can I get the clipboard data of an android phone in my C# winforms application?

Tags: c#, android, winforms

I have a windows application developed in c#. It has one particular form with a textbox control.

How can I get the clipboard data of an android phone (data which is saved in the clipboard) in my windows application.

P.S.: We already have an android application that is doing the necessary work and saving the results in the clipboard. Now my team needs to retrieve those results from the android clipboard.

Comment: Check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6651184/set-text-and-get-text-from-clipboard

Comment: Have you even read my question and then compared it with the link you suggested.?