# how to check clipboard copied data is number or text?

Tags: android

I have made a `Edittext` that contains a data which i copied from `Clipboard`. so I want to check that copied data is text or number in android only. Please help me if you know

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if a String is numeric in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102891/how-to-check-if-a-string-is-numeric-in-java)

Comment: Also check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6651184/set-text-and-get-text-from-clipboard

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the test from clipboard, you can use `ClipboardManager` to do that.

```
ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) 
getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
   try {
     CharSequence textToPaste = clipboard.getPrimaryClip().getItemAt(0).getText();
   } catch (Exception e) {
     return;
}
```

> I want to check that copied data is text or number in android only

Since you have to use [`getText()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ClipData.Item#getText()) it will return a `CharSequence`, so if you want to detect if what's inside this `CharSequence` is a number or string you'll have to do some algorithm to get that, something like this :

You can use `Character.isNumber()` to check if it's a number or `Character.isLetter()` to check if it's a `string`.

For example :

```
for (char c : yourDataFromClipboard.toCharArray()) {
    if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
       Character.getNumericValue(c); //is a number
    }
    else if(Character.isLetter(c)){
       //is string 
    }
}
```